# MassGIS Data Layer & PostGIS lat/lon not finding correct gemos

Tags: postgis

I am using the MassGIS House District data layer with `srid 26986`. I then query for the geom containing the lat/lon `42.21, -71.5` which should give me Boston but I got nothing. So I used OpenJump to visualize this and the point is rendering a few hundred miles south of the House District geoms:
[image]

I am guessing there is something wrong with the projection but according to multiple sources this is the correct `srid`: http://www.mass.gov/anf/research-and-tech/it-serv-and-support/application-serv/office-of-geographic-information-massgis/datalayers/overview.html.

Any pointers?

Comment: This is not an issue of having the lat/lon backwards. I am correctly declaring the points as: `select st_point(-71.5, 42.21);`

Comment: You're working in the wrong coord system. By that I mean, you just put a point at 71.5 meters west of the origin, 42.21 meters north of the origin of the Mass State Plane coordinate origin. So you need to translate either your data from srid 26986 to a lat lon projection (like 4326), or translate your st_point() query to reflect that you're using Mass State Plane Coordinates, not degrees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the projection, it probably just needs to be transformed correctly:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-71.5, 42.21), 4326), 26986));

                st_astext
------------------------------------------
 POINT(200000.000000001 884394.318987381)
```